# Does writing XPath Queries require to know DTD?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, dtd

I am writing some XPath queries for some XML files. However, the DTDs of those files are unavailable, though I have some basic ideas about the structure of the XML files.

I am wondering **should we assume the DTDs are always available when writing XPath queries?**

(I am new to XPath, pls correct me if I am not asking the right question).

Comment: So are you just walking in complete darkness writing guesses and hoping it will work?

Comment: No, it's not required to have a DTD to write XPath.

Comment: I write them all the time, and I've never seen or had a DTD related to any of the files I receive. (Many have XSDs, but none has a DTD.) What makes you think you would need one?

Comment: @KenWhite Very helpful comments. I thought to write XPath query, it requires to know the XML structure. So he/she has to have a DTD or XSD. Please correct me if I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @KenWhite When you say "Many have XSDs", I am wondering how you get the XSD. Do you receive it before XML stream, or is it part of the XML stream, or some other way?

Comment: None of the above. It's typically established and obtained beforehand, normally from the supplier of the XML. We sometimes design it in collaboration with the team we will be exchanging data with, or something already exists at one side or the other (a company standard XSD, or an industry standard, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having access to a DTD will make a difference to your ability to understand the expected or intended structure of the data (although unless the situation allows you to know that the data will all be DTD-valid, the data may have a different structure in fact).

Having, or not having, a DTD will make no difference in the ability of an XQuery, XSLT, or other XPath processor to handle your queries.  (Some XQuery processors may expect or require an XSD schema, some XQuery processors and some XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processors will exploit one if available, but I am not aware of any XPath processor of any kind that expects, requires, or uses a DTD.)

Comment: Very useful answer! Thanks a lot. I am wondering if you know any references (papers/documents/webpage/...) I can cite?

Comment: Cite for what?  Are you trying to win an argument with a colleague who doesn't want to take your word for it?  Or trying to put a footnote into an academic paper or technical report?  And what point are you trying to support?  The claim that document grammars can help convey the expected structure of the data?  I don't know any; the point follows directly from the function of document grammars.  The claim that XQuery processors do not require access to DTDs?  Follows from the relevant specs (look for them at http://www.w3.org/TR/).